# Why reordering commits using git rebase -i doesn't screw up the history?

Tags: git

As I understand it, commits are snapshots of *files* so if I perform change A and then change B, change B's commit *file* already includes the changes in change A, wouldn't reordering make change A redundant?

Comment: Git does diffs as needed; rebase applies diffs to new base content.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is, in fact, a very good question, because commits *are* snapshots.

The reason rebase works is because rebase is actually repeated `git cherry-pick` (with a bit of wrapping at the front to figure out what to pick, and more at the end to move the branch labels), and `git cherry-pick` works by *turning a commit into a change-set*.

Suppose for instance that you have this sequence of commits:

```
          A--B--C   <-- topic
         /
...--o--*--o--o     <-- mainline
```

To rebase `topic` onto `mainline` we need to (1) find the commits that are on `topic` but not on `mainline` (which are `C`, `B`, and `A` along the top row, ending at the commit marked `*`), and then (2) copy them to new commits we will add on below the tip of `mainline`.

Rebase first finds the three post-`*` commits and puts them into a (reverse ordered: `A`, `B`, `C`) list (it also omits merge commits by default but there are no merges here).  It then does a cherry pick for each commit.

To cherry-pick `A`, Git diffs `A` against `*`.  This turns the two snapshots into changesets.  Git then applies the changes to the tip-most commit of `mainline` and makes a new commit, let's call it `A'`, on an anonymous branch:

```
          A--B--C   <-- topic
         /
...--o--*--o--o     <-- mainline
               \
                A'  <-- HEAD
```

To cherry-pick `B`, Git diffs `B` against `A`.  Applying these changes to `A'` produces another commit `B'`.  Repeat for `C` to obtain `C'`:

```
          A--B--C         <-- topic
         /
...--o--*--o--o           <-- mainline
               \
                A'-B'-C'  <-- HEAD
```

Last, Git peels the `topic` label away from `C` and points it to `C'` instead.  The old chain is abandoned (though you can still find it through reflogs, and `rebase` copies the ID of `C` to the special name `ORIG_HEAD` as well):

```
          A--B--C         [abandoned]
         /
...--o--*--o--o           <-- mainline
               \
                A'-B'-C'  <-- topic
```

and now the rebase is complete.

Note that each copy is done using git's merge mechanisms if needed (if the diffs do not apply cleanly right away).  Each one can result in a merge conflict, requiring rebase to stop and get help from you.  (Or, worse, you can get a mis-merge, although these are rare in practice.)

And of course, if you re-order the commits (by moving `pick` lines around in an interactive rebase), we just change the order we pick and apply each commit.  The cherry-pick operations still work the same way: compare the picked commit against its parent (`C` vs `B`, `A` vs `*`, `B` vs `A`).

Comment: But the diffs data depends on what were the contents of the file in the previous commit, which would change after reordering them. Or is this reorder only cosmetic?

Comment: The new copies are *new copies*, with all that this implies.  Suppose, for instance, that while cherry-picking `B` you get a merge conflict because the tip of `mainline` has a conflicting change.  When you fix up the conflict and continue the rebase, the new commit `B'` now has a different change from the original commit `B`.  Both `B` and `B'` are still in the repository, and the next cherry-pick (assuming it is for `C`) compares `C` to `B` before attempting to apply that change to `B'` (which may get another merge conflict since `B'` is now different!).

Comment: I think I see it now after reading your comment and re-reading your answer. It seems I just got thrown off by the terminology. As I see it now, sure, the commits can be reordered but the resulting commits after a rebase are completely new commits whether you reordered them or not. This resulting commits also have a different "snapshot file" that is the result of just applying the diff from the cherry-picking to the tip of mainline. In that way, the reorder is cosmetic since the original commits that were reordered are left unchanged. Please let me know if I'm right.

Comment: Yes, you are right, at least under the right conditions. You can work this as a sort of algebra as well. Suppose you start with a number (like x=10). Then you have commits that change x: x=12, x=5, x=6. Convert each to a delta: +2, -7, +1.  Re-order the deltas: -7, +1, +2.  Apply to 10 to get 10-7=3, +1=4, +2=6. The *end result* is the same. The *intermediates* might be different though.  The re-ordering fails only if one of the intermediates depends on another intermediate, e.g., if commit C needs something B did.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks!